# Ratio between forward and reverse conditional probability

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I have a probability distribution $p(Z | X)$ from which I can easily sample and compute the probability at every value for $Z$ and $X$. The inverse distribution $p(X | Z)$ however can be very complex and evaluation at given $Z$ and $X$ can be intractable.

I need to calculate the ratio:

$\frac{p(Z | X)}{p(X | Z)}$

It can be seen as a measurement for irreversibility or the increase in entropy.

Is it possible to calculate this ratio without the need to calculate or model the inverse probability distribution ?

Is there literature dealing with similar problems ?

Comment: Bayes' theorem says that your ratio is equal to $\frac{p(Z)}{p(X)}$. Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since $P(X \cap Z)=P(X \mid Z)P(Z) =P(Z \mid X)P(X)$ then providing none of these are zero, you can say $$\frac{ P(Z\mid X ) }{P(X \mid Z)}  = \frac{P(Z )}{P(X )}$$ and $${P(X \mid Z)=  \frac{ P(Z\mid X ) P(X )}{P(Z )}}$$

Comment: Computing $P(X)$ or $P(Z)$ is not possible in my case and as hard as computing $P(X|Z)$. And I am not allowed to assume any distributions for $P(X)$ or $P(Z)$.

Comment: @karlma: If $P(X\cap Z)$ is also too hard to compute then you seem to be in an impossible position